# How to resolve the error of processing multiple pdf files in R script

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining

```
library(readtext)
data_dir <- system.file("E:/project_refrences", package = "readtext")
rt7 <- readtext(paste0(data_dir, "*.pdf"), docvarsfrom = "filenames", 
                 docvarnames = c("document", "language"))
```

I tried and getting this Error while processing multiple pdf files:

```
## PDF error: xref num 65 not found but needed, try to reconstruct<0a>
## PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
## PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
## PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
## PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
## PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
```

---

I also tried by applying `for` loop:

```
pdf <- Sys.glob("*.pdf")
for(i in pdf){
    rt <- readtext((i), docvarfrom = "filenames", docvarnames = c("document", "language"))}
```

but getting same above mentioned error.
How can I fix this error or work around it?

Comment: Maybe the package pdftools might help.

Comment: I tried pdftools but is has same problem with it... if you are having a code please share with us. @phiver